# First C Program- Mastermind

Tags: beginner, c

This is my first full program I've written in C. It took me about 2 hours to pull together today. Looking for any sort of feedback on the code, formatting, cleanliness etc. I didn't follow any guides or tutorials, but did have some existing C++ knowledge and knowledge in other languages.

The game is Mastermind. The way it works is that the computer generates a 4 color code randomly from a pool of 7 colors. Then, the user must guess what the code is in as few guesses as possible. The user must guess 4 colors, and the feedback given is how many colors of the guess are a part of the code, and how many of the colors are placed correctly.

There's more on the Wikipedia page: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define RESET  "\x1B[0m"
#define BLOCK  "█"

#define RED   "\x1B[31m" BLOCK RESET
#define GRN   "\x1B[32m" BLOCK RESET
#define YEL   "\x1B[33m" BLOCK RESET
#define BLU   "\x1B[34m" BLOCK RESET
#define MAG   "\x1B[35m" BLOCK RESET
#define CYN   "\x1B[36m" BLOCK RESET
#define WHT   "\x1B[37m" BLOCK RESET

#define RED_C   "\x1B[31m"
#define GRN_C   "\x1B[32m"
#define YEL_C   "\x1B[33m"
#define BLU_C   "\x1B[34m"
#define MAG_C   "\x1B[35m"
#define CYN_C   "\x1B[36m"
#define WHT_C   "\x1B[37m"

#define COLORS 6
#define LENGTH 4

enum Colors {
    red,
    green,
    yellow,
    blue,
    magenta,
    cyan,
    white
};

static const enum Colors Color_map[] = {red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, white};

void *generate_colors(enum Colors *buffer)
{
    int power = pow(COLORS + 1, LENGTH);
    int colors_integer = rand() % power;

    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; ++i)
    {
        int remainder = colors_integer % (COLORS + 1);
        int divisor = colors_integer / (COLORS + 1);

        buffer[i] = Color_map[remainder];

        colors_integer = divisor;
    }
}

int convert_input(char *input, enum Colors *buffer)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < strlen(input); ++c)
    {
        char character = tolower(input[c]);

        switch (character)
        {
            case 'r':
                buffer[c] = red;
                break;

            case 'g':
                buffer[c] = green;
                break;

            case 'y':
                buffer[c] = yellow;
                break;

            case 'b':
                buffer[c] = blue;
                break;

            case 'm':
                buffer[c] = magenta;
                break;

            case 'c':
                buffer[c] = cyan;
                break;

            case 'w':
                buffer[c] = white;
                break;

            default:
                return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

char *color_to_char(enum Colors color)
{
    switch (color)
    {
        case red:
            return RED;
        case green:
            return GRN;
        case yellow:
            return YEL;
        case blue:
            return BLU;
        case magenta:
            return MAG;
        case cyan:
            return CYN;
        default:
            return WHT;
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    enum Colors selected_colors[4];
    generate_colors(selected_colors);

    int guessed = 0;

    do {
        char input[LENGTH];
        scanf("%s", input);

        if (strlen(input) == LENGTH)
        {
            enum Colors converted[LENGTH];
            int contains_unmatched = convert_input(input, converted);

            int correct_place = 0;
            int correct_color = 0;

            if (contains_unmatched)
            {
                printf("Please only choose characters from " RED_C "R, " GRN_C "G, " YEL_C "Y, " BLU_C "B, " MAG_C "M, " CYN_C "C, " WHT_C "W" RESET ".\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("You guessed: ");

                for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; ++i)
                {
                    enum Colors color = converted[i];
                    enum Colors actual = selected_colors[i];

                    if (color == actual)
                        ++correct_place;

                    else 
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < LENGTH; ++j)
                        {
                            if (j != i)
                            {
                                enum Colors current = selected_colors[j];

                                if (color == current)
                                {
                                    ++correct_color;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    printf("%s", color_to_char(converted[i]));
                }

                if (correct_place == LENGTH)
                {
                    printf("Well done! You got it right. Goodbye");
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\n %d correct color\n %d correct place and color\n", correct_color, correct_place);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Please enter 4 characters.\n");
        }
    } while (!guessed);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation on what this is (supposed to be) doing?

Comment: @yuri https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game) and maybe also https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/202809/a-simple-mastermind-clone/202848

Comment: BTW, the program has  a bug. Obviously noticeable with input like `RRRR` it can state: `2 correct color 2 correct place and color`. How to I swap my `R`'s  to the correct order :-) If the hidden code only has two `R` it should report `0 correct color 2 correct place and color`.

Answer (score 1):

- Maybe have a scheme to keep header files sorted. Makes it easier to spot possible duplicate includes.
- `enum Colors` should be `enum Color`, every enum instance in only one at a time.
- To keep track of a true enumerated sequence add max enum to keep track of the number of colors.

  ```
  magenta,
  cyan,
  white,

  COLORS }; // == 7
  ```

  (Thus, don't forget to remove `#define COLORS 6`.)
- `Color_map` not really needed in this case since they are nicely enumerated. Just replace `buffer[i] = Color_map[remainder];` with `buffer[i] = (enum Color)remainder;`.
- Doesn't look like `void *generate_colors(enum Colors *buffer)` is returning anything, so just make it `void generate_colors(...`.
- Since `COLORS` now is `7` instead of `6`, replace all `COLORS + 1` with just `COLORS`.
- In `generate_colors`, `int power ...` can be `const int power ...`.
- Interface to `convert_input` can be `const` for its input, i.e., `int convert_input(const char *input, enum Color *buffer)`.
- Simplify and speed up start of loop. E.g., don't check `strlen(input)` every interation, it's not changing. No need to call `strlen` (see below). `tolower` needs `unsigned char` to guarantee proper functionality, thus, platform dependent on signess of `char`.

Example

```
for (int c = 0;; ++c) // Look, no check for end of string done here
{
    switch (tolower((unsigned char)input[c]))
    {
        case 'r':
```

...

```
            case '\0': // add end-of-string check here
                return 0;
            default:
                return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

- `const char *color_to_char(enum Colors color)` since it return `const` strings.
- Input handling not kind on the user when entering wrong. Instead, read the whole line and parse the line for you guess.

Example

```
char* line = NULL;
size_t line_len = 0u;

while (!guessed && getline(&line, &line_len, stdin) != -1)
{
    char input[LENGTH + 1]; // OBS: This was too small before
    sscanf(line, " %4s", input); // automatic skip of white space
                                 // and limit input to 4 real characters
                                 // discarding the rest of the line.
```

- Split wide `printf` statement and don't color the commas.

Snippet:

```
printf("%s\n", "Please only choose characters from "
RED_C "R" RESET ", "
GRN_C "G" RESET ", "
YEL_C "Y" RESET ", "
BLU_C "B" RESET ", "
MAG_C "M" RESET ", "
CYN_C "C" RESET ", "
WHT_C "W" RESET ".");
```

- And if you use `getline`, free memory at end.

Snippet:

```
}

free(line);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

Comment: Thank you, there's lots for me to consider here! I'm curious as to why it's necessary to free memory before exiting the program- is this not something the OS should do automatically?

Comment: For me it's just customary, but is really help memory leak tools to help me identify the different types of leaks a program might have. By not `free`-ing it's harder to tell if if you have unintentional memory leaks that might eat up memory in the long run. But mostly, the OS will return the memory.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Another small query: I realize you replaced a `do..while` loop with a `while` loop. Is the only reason for this to do with the usage of `getline` in it, or are `do..while` loops something that should be generally avoided?

Comment: Generally prefer `while/for` over `do..while`. They make it easier to understand the logic. In this case it was also to combine the termination of `getline` with your `guessed` logic.